# Problem adding an MDExpansionPanel in a RecycleView Python/Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

*I'm not able to add an `MDExpansionPanel`  object in the RecycleView's data variable*

**main.py:**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.expansionpanel import MDExpansionPanelOneLine

Builder.load_string("""
<MyRecycleView>:
    viewclass: "MDExpansionPanel"
    effect_cls: "ScrollEffect"
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: dp(10)
""")

class MyRecycleView(RecycleView):
    pass

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        recycle = MyRecycleView()
        recycle.data = [
            {
                "content":None,
                "icon":"arrow-right",
                "panel_cls":MDExpansionPanelOneLine(
                    text="Test"
                )
            }
        ]
        return recycle

MyApp().run()
```

**This returns an error:**

```
ValueError: KivyMD: `panel_cls` object must be must be one of the objects from the list
 [MDExpansionPanelOneLine, MDExpansionPanelTwoLine, MDExpansionPanelThreeLine]
```

*I tried another way by creating a custom `MDExpansionPanel`  that already has the `MDExpansionPanelOneLine`  in the `panel_cls`  attribute and setting a property text to put in the text attribute of  `MDExpansionPanelOneLine`*

**main.py**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.expansionpanel import MDExpansionPanel
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Builder.load_string("""
#:import MDExpansionPanelOneLine kivymd.uix.expansionpanel.MDExpansionPanelOneLine

<MyRecycleView>:
    viewclass: "MyExpansionPanel"
    effect_cls: "ScrollEffect"
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: dp(10)

<MyExpansionPanel>:
    content: None
    panel_cls:
        MDExpansionPanelOneLine(\
            text=root.text
        )
""")

class MyRecycleView(RecycleView):
    pass

class MyExpansionPanel(MDExpansionPanel):
    text = StringProperty()

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        recycle = MyRecycleView()
        recycle.data = [
            {
                "icon":"arrow-right",
                "text":"Test"
            }
        ]
        return recycle

MyApp().run()
```

*This works but the text attribute of `MDExpansionPanelOneLine` doesn't change, the `text` property on the `RecycleView` data variable doesn't work.*

**Any idea how I can set a  `text`  attribute of an object that is inside  `panel_cls`  in the  `RecycleView`  data variable?**

Comment: Your second approach should've worked if you added some `content`.

Comment: It worked, but the real problem was that I couldn't update the `attributes` of the class instantiated in `panel_cls`. I read more the `RecycleView` documentation and it solved the problem, I will answer. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I solved the problem by inheriting the `RecycleDataViewBehavior`  class in the `MyExpansionPanel`  class and redefining the `refresh_view_attrs`  function and changing the `text`  attribute of `panel_cls`  in which the `MDExpansionPanelOneLine`  class is instantiated.*

**main.py**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.expansionpanel import MDExpansionPanel, MDExpansionPanelOneLine
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Builder.load_string("""
#:import MDExpansionPanelOneLine kivymd.uix.expansionpanel.MDExpansionPanelOneLine

<MyRecycleView>:
    viewclass: "MyExpansionPanel"
    effect_cls: "ScrollEffect"
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: dp(10)

<MyExpansionPanel>:
    content: None
""")

class MyRecycleView(RecycleView):
    pass

class MyExpansionPanel(MDExpansionPanel, RecycleDataViewBehavior):
    text = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.panel_cls = MDExpansionPanelOneLine()
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        self.panel_cls.text = data["text"]
        return super().refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        recycle = MyRecycleView()
        recycle.data = [
            {
                "icon":"arrow-right",
                "text":"Test"
            }
        ]
        return recycle

MyApp().run()
```

*And the `text`  attribute that is defined in the `data`  variable of

`RecycleView`  is updated text attribute of `MDExpansionPanelOneLine`.*